# Alternative to mass Try Catch blocks for my logic

Tags: java, design

Currently I'm working on creating something with the following general structure. I want to call 4 different APIs in sequential order (the results of one are needed for the next one). If one throws an exception, undo the efforts of the previous APIs with their sister delete APIs.

Currently my structure/ control flow looks like:

```java
boolean A = false;
boolean B = false;
boolean C = false;
boolean D = false;
string response = StringUtils.EMPTY

try {
   API_A;
   A = true;
}
catch (A's Exceptions {
    response = "fail!"
}

if (boolean_A == false){
   undo_if_stuff_to_undo;
   return response;
}
```

Basically this repeated  3 times and if all 4 were successful my response would say success. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to approach this. I thought about making a function for each API call that returned a boolean but the problem was that I needed the results from each API to call the next. Perhaps creating a special class for each API result that would store its success/failure and relevant attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...  I thought about making a function for each API call that returned a boolean but the problem was that I needed the results from each API to call the next...

Then don't use a boolean; [use an `Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). That way, you test for success of each function with `result.IsPresent()` and rollback if not.

So you can then create functions that wrap the try/catch logic for each API and return an empty optional for a failure and an optional with the result for a success and chain them together as you describe.

Comment: Ah I see so for each API helper funciton I create its just

```java
private Optional<T> apiAhelper(....)
return null if catches exception
return response object if it works well
```

Comment: @PLfan666, exactly.

Comment: And then I just put my response object in the Optional yea?
So if API A returns an API_A_Response object itd be 
Optional<API_A_Response> ?

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks like the case for [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) pattern. As your A, B, etc do not implement the AutoCloseable, you could do something like (I don't know java very well so may write something wrong):

```
abstract class WithRollback<T> : AutoCloseable {
 // fields instead of properties here for shortness
 public bool if_rollback;
 public T data;
 public WithRollback(T data) { this.data = data; this.if_rollback = true; }
 public void close() { if (this.if_rollback) { this.rollback(this.data); } }
 abstract void rollback(T);
}

try (
 resA = new WithRollback<A>(makeA;) { void rollback(A data) {undoA;} };
 resB = new WithRollback<B>(makeB;) { void rollback(B data) {undoB;} };
 resC = new WithRollback<C>(makeC;) { void rollback(C data) {undoC;} };
 resD = new WithRollback<D>(makeD;) { void rollback(D data) {undoD;} }
) {
 resA.if_rollback = false;
 resB.if_rollback = false;
 resC.if_rollback = false;
 resD.if_rollback = false;
}
```

so that exiting the scope with perform rollback until you mark all of the successful